# net standard 1.6 WCF Client InvalidOperationException: System.Xml.Linq.XElement cannot be used as: 'xml text'

Tags: c#, wcf, security, .net-standard

I need some assistance in solving some unusual problem.
The main aspecs are in issue on github: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2150

I've tried to add some interceptors (IClientMessageInspector, IParameterInspector), but they are never been called.

After all DebuggerStepThroughAttribute has been removed, the problem seems to be in a channel itself. The SOAP Server itself implemented with java.

Do someone had similar problem?